# Infinite series with cos in numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you evaluate this series?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos i}{2^i}$$

It's absolutely convergent by comparison to the geometric series. But the $\cos$ is tripping me up. I've tried differentiating in order to go through the $\cos$ -> $\sin$ -> $\cos$ route, but that gives me different powers of 2 in the denominator. Any ideas?

Comment: Write $\cos x$ as $\frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$ (your use of $i$ as the indexing variable is very unfortunate for this reason). Also, what are you differentiating?

Comment: Thanks. I was differentiating w.r.t. i inside the sum, but in retrospect that's nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos n}{2^n}=\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{e^i}{2}\right)^n = \text{Re}\left(\frac{e^i}{2-e^i}\right)=\text{Re}\left(\frac{2e^i-1}{5-4\cos 1}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{2\cos 1-1}{5-4\cos 1}}. $$

Comment: That's great, thanks. You've made it very clear.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. One may write, for $|q|<1$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^n \cos(n\alpha)=\Re \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (qe^{i\alpha})^n =\Re\: \frac{qe^{i\alpha}}{1-qe^{i\alpha}}
$$ where we have used the standard evaluation of a geometric series.

Comment: Darn, beat me to it. (As a side remark: here was used the fact that the real-part is linear, i.e. $\mathfrak{R}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathfrak{R}a_k$.)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So easy once you see how.

Comment: @Number 34 You are welcome.